# Cypher query to return graph as object, where each parent node contains an array of its children?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a graph like the one below:

[image]

**What cypher query must I use to return the graph as an object, where each parent node contains an array of its children nodes?**

Example:

```
state: {
  name: 'New York'
  publishingCompanies: [
    {
      name: 'Penguin'
      authors: [
        {
          name: 'George Orwell',
          books: [
            { name: 'Why I Write'},
            { name: 'Animal Farm'},
            { name: '1984' }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'Vladimir Nobokov'
          books: [
            { name: 'Lolita' }
          ]
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    { 
      name: 'Random House',
      authors: [
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use `apoc.convert.toTree`, but it returned an array of paths from `State` to `Book`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should return the `state` object (assuming the state name is passed in via the `stateName` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)):

```
MATCH (s:State)
WHERE s.name = $stateName
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:IS_STATE_OF]->(c)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:PUBLISHED_FOR]->(a)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:WROTE]->(b)
WITH s, c, a, CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT({name: b.name}) END AS books
WITH s, c, CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT({name: a.name, books: books}) END AS authors
WITH s, CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN [] ELSE COLLECT({name: c.name, authors: authors}) END AS pcs
RETURN {name: s.name, publishingCompanies: pcs} AS state
```

Comment: Updated the clause that creates `books` so that the elements will match the desired results.